# Standard projection for Brazil?

Tags: coordinate-system, brazil

I'm trying to find a "standard" map projection for Brazil, by which I mean one that Brazilian users would be familiar with.

This is how Brazil maps look in Infogram, can anyone suggest which projection it might be?

[image]

Comment: The best way to identify this would be to locate some Brazilian users.  Or Brazilian cartographers. This is likely *too broad/opinion-based* for our "Focused question / Best answer" model.

Comment: It depends too much on what you're trying to map. If you're looking to represent the entire country small scale, you could probably settle with a Pseudo-Mercator. There's a polyconic projection, EPSG:5880 that could also be of interest. If you were trying to make maps of larger-scale smaller regions, the usual UTM would be a good fallback.

In any case, when you compare the country boundaries with web-mercator and polyconic, the difference isn't all that great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [EPSG Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org) lists several "Brazil Polyconic" projected coordinate reference systems. The most recent is EPSG::5880, SIRGAS 2000 / Brazil Polyconic. The source is listed as Petrobras, but the usage is listed as Brazil onshore and offshore.

There's also a Mercator-based one listed but its usage is offshore only.

Note: Gabriel C. listed 5880 in a comment; I didn't notice that until I'd already written this answer.